# Sencha EXT-JS 4: How to update data in store

Tags: extjs, store

I have a model defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.TestModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'p1'
        },
        {
            name: 'p2'
        },
        {
            name: 'p3'
        },
        {
            name: 'p5'
        },
        {
            name: 'p6'
        },
        {
            name: 'p7'
        }
    ]
});
```

The store is defined as follows:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.TestStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.TestModel'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: 'TestStoreID',
            model: 'MyApp.model.TestModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'getparams',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'getdata.params'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

the controller uses ajax proxy to load data as follows:

```
var sIndex = 1;
AppGlobals.mystore = Ext.getStore('PollStore');
AppGlobals.mystore.load({params: {id: sIndex, p1:'1',p2:'2', p3:'3', p4:'5', p5:'6', p6:'7'}});
```

All this is working fine. I would like to modify the values of p1, p2, p3, p5, p6, p7 right where the load command is written. That is, instead of callint mystore.load() is there any way I can load hard coded data directly into the store?

I mean, lets say I have 6 values defined as

```
var p1val = 1;
var p2val = 2;
var p3val = 3;
var p5val = 4;
var p6val = 5;
var p7val = 6;
```

is there anyway I can do the following:

```
AppGlobals.mystore = Ext.getStore('PollStore');
AppGlobals.mystore.somefunction(p1val, p2val, p3val, p5val, p6val, p7val);
```

where `somefunction()` can update the values in the store immeadiately and I don't have to call the `load()` function which will be going and getting data from proxy?

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a method to do exactly this. You are looking for the **loadData** method. [Here is a link to the method in Sencha Docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData)

Make sure to note it takes two parameters - the array of records (data), and whether to wipe the current store records. By default **loadData** first removes any existing data in the store, which I think is what you want to do anyway - if so, you just need the first array parameter.

Here is a code example of how the issue could be solved:

```
 store.loadData(data, false);
 grid.reconfigure(store);
```